# Move sessions in Chrome to a different computer

Tags: google-chrome, browser, passwords

I need to move my browsing session in Chrome to a different computer.

For example, on my current computer, I have sessions saved for Gmail, Facebook etc.  So, I can go to Facebook.com and it will not prompt me to login (even after a restart).  I need to move over these and many other sessions to a new computer which also has Chrome installed.

I want to still be able to go into any of the sites such as Gmail or Facebook and not be asked to log in at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's built into Chrome - see here - https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2591582?hl=en

Comment: I know that this moves the tabs and favorites. But does it move the logged in sessions. Such as Facebook etc. ?

Comment: as far as I know, yes. it also save my search history from machine to machine.